# Other apps not allowed in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm working on an iOS app in Objective-C and I'm currently trying to make a sharing extension with a `UIActivityViewController`.

I understand that there is an enum of activity that I can individually exclude from the `UIActivityViewController` with a property of type `NSArray` called `excludedActivityTypes`.

How can I also exclude other apps (such as Pinterest or LinkedIn) that the user can manually add/activate/disable from the panel that shows when you hit the "`Other`" button in the `UIActivityViewController` ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I also exclude other apps (such as Pinterest or LinkedIn) that the user can manually add/activate/disable from the panel

You cannot. Of course you could try going to the user's house and pinning his arms behind his back, but, short of that, you are not in charge of what the user does.